# flock(), then fgets(): low-level locks, then stdio read/write library functions. Is it possible?

Tags: c, stdio, locks, flock

I'm writing a server web.

Each connection is served by a separate thread, so **I don't know in advance the number of threads**.

There are also a group of text files (don't know the number, too), and each thread can read/write on each file.

A file can be written by just one thread a time, but different threads can write on different files at the same time.

If a file is read by one or more threads (reads can be concurrent), no thread can write on THAT file.

Now, I noticed this ([Thread safe multi-file writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998778/thread-safe-multi-file-writing)) solution, but I'd like also to use functions as fgets(), for example.

So, can I *flock()* a file, and then use a fgets() or another stdio read/write library function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, use `fcntl`, not `flock`. The latter is a non-standard, deprecated BSD function and does not work with NFS and possibly other filesystems. `fcntl` locking on the other hand is POSIX standard and is *intended* to work everywhere.

Now if you want to use file-level reader-writer locking mixed with stdio, it will work, but you have to take some care to ensure that buffering does not break your assumptions about locks. The method I'm about to explain is not the only one, but I believe it's the clearest/simplest:

When you want to operate on one of your files with stdio, obtaining the correct type of lock (read or write, aka shared of exclusive) should be the first thing you do after `fopen`. Use `fileno` to get the file descriptor number and apply the lock to it. After that, perform your entire read or write operation. **Do not** make any attempt to unlock the file; instead, call `fclose` to close the file and let it be implicitly unlocked when it's closed. Otherwise you may release the lock while unbuffered data is still unwritten, or later read data that was buffered before the lock was released, that's no longer valid after the lock is released.

Comment: Another bonus with `fcntl` locks is that they will auto-release on process exit (including exit due to being killed externally or running into a bug and seg-faulting or similar).

Comment: Can I be assured that if different threads open the same file, they obtain different file descriptors?
If not, I can't use `fcntl` beacuse if any thread close the file descriptor, others loses their lock.

Comment: Yes they obtain different file descriptors, but I believe you would have the problem that the lock is released whenever any descriptor referring to the same **file** (not just open file description, but **file**) is closed: "All locks associated with a file for a given process shall be removed when a file descriptor for that file is closed by that process or the process holding that file descriptor terminates."

Comment: Maybe I should give up low level I\O and rely on library functions as `flockfile`, using in this case the streams on `FILE *`

Comment: Indeed, if you can use `FILE` streams, `flockfile` would be ideal. Even if you want to to low-level file descriptor io, you could encapsulate the fd in a `FILE` just for the purpose of associating a lock with it. That's slightly more costly than just using your own structure with a mutex to encapsulate it, but it might be useful if you ever want to mix low-level io and stdio on it (which is possible as long as you follow the POSIX rules for switching between the two).

Comment: Hmm, I think I forgot to look back at your question. `flockfile` locks the open file stream, **not** the underlying file on disk. If your threads are each opening the file independently (and thus have their own `FILE *` for it), `flockfile` will not do any useful locking at all. You might need to switch to just using lockfiles on disk or something...